# Derived category of an abelian monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory, derived-categories, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories, abelian-categories

For any abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, we can consider its derived category $\mathcal{D(A)}$, which is naturally triangulated. If  $\mathcal{A}$ is endowed with a monoidal structure (bilinear with respect to biproducts) does this imply some extra structure on $\mathcal{D(A)}$? If so, how does this extra structure interact with the triangular structure of $\mathcal{D(A)}$?

Comment: In principle you need "enough flat objects" in $\mathcal{A}
$. Using the acyclicity properties to derived the monoidal product you may proceed as on sheaves of modules over a ringed space where there are not enough projectives.

Comment: Presumably one would hope that at least under suitable hypotheses on $\mathcal{A}$, the category $\mathcal{D}(A)$ would itself be monoidal, compatibly with the triangulated structure as in the papers cited at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+triangulated+category.